# How to display div content on the next line instead of inline in a collapsable <a>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am implementing a sidebar with bootstrap 5.

I would like to get something like this if I click the user initials (collapse):

[image]

But instead I'm getting this:

[image]

I think it's related with `d-flex`, found several questions on SO but none of them solved my problem.

How can I 'separate' the content in two blocks and add a breakline between them instead of creating two columns?

[JS FIDDLE LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/30/)

Relevant part code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary d-flex" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sidebarUserProfile" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidebarUserProfile">
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="userInitials">JW</span>
                            <div class="d-flex text flex-row align-items-center staff-nav-holder">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                    <span class="staff-name fw-bold">John Walker</span>
                                    <span class="staff-position">PM</span>
                                </div>
                                <i id="profile-chevron-down" class="bi bi-chevron-down ml-2">
                                </i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="collapse d-block" id="sidebarUserProfile">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                                <li>Customize your homepage</li>
                                <li>Change your password</li>
                                <li>Log out</li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </p>
                </li>
            ...
           </ul>
```

Comment: can you add a minimal code example of just the relevant part? If you use rows/columns this should be easy

Comment: You've got a row with no cols in it, row has display flex. I wonder why you don't put the parts in bootstrap columns. When you use a bootstrap row, it should have at least one bootstap col in it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately adding columns in both divs doesn't change anything

Comment: I actually meant you should build the layout with col classes instead of d-flex. thats a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are using the "d-block" class in the collapsed item.
a collapsed item can`t have a 'd-block' class Because it means: `'display: block;'`
That it is against the rule:

```
.collapse:not(.show) {
    display: none;
}
```

see this pen:
https://codepen.io/witty_code/pen/zYdwbZW

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in your provided pen I still have two columns, how to add  a 'break line' between them?

Comment: I edited my pen to answer this question, I just added the class: `flex-column`. 
Another solution I applied with [this another pen](https://codepen.io/witty_code/pen/mdMBdzo), is to replace the `d-flex` class with the `row` class (automatically defined in bootstrap as: `display: flex;`) and for the elements within it I gave the `col-12` class instead of `row`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated my fiddle a little bit. Could you edit the pen to match the new fiddle content? I'll mark your answer as correct then :)

Comment: Your file is large. can you say briefly what have you changed?